# Show another-example.com as example.com/another in browser (2 domains/WordPress installations on 1 domain)

Tags: wordpress, apache, redirect, dns, forwarding

the company I work for currently owns two domains, e.g.:

1. example.com
2. another-example.com

I manage the WordPress installations, which run on those domains (two distinct installations with separate themes, plugins, webspaces, databases, ftp, etc.), in my free time as they always come up with challenging requirements which helps me improve my skills (and because the company is really nice to me in general).

They've asked me if it was possible to redirect another-example.com to example.com/another and display everything from the second WordPress installation under that URL.

For example the main page of another-example.com should be displayed under example.com/another, the subpage another-example.com/about-us should be displayed under example.com/another/about-us and so on.

All the WordPress pages of example.com should continue to work as they are now ("another" would in reality a word which would never be used as subpage of the main domain, so that won't ever be an issue). Basically they just want the browser to display example.com/another instead of another-example.com for "tracking, SEO and usability" (I didn't question that... ).

I just wanted to know whether this is possible or not.

One idea that came to my mind was to setup example.com as WordPress multisite installation and run another-example.com as subsite of that multisite on /another. Though I'm not very familiar with multisite, I blieve this is how it could work and it surely isn't to hard to migrate a normal WordPress installation to become a subsite of a multisite. I'm familiar with databases so worst case is I have to do some manual labor if it isn't already possible out of the box by using some backup plugin or so.

But I was thinking that maybe it is possible by changing some settings in the webservers. It's just that Apache HTTP servers aren't really my world at all and even though I tried to understand the configs multiple times over the last decade, I never did and I have no clue how that would work (if it is possible at all).

So my question is: Is it possible to achieve this by configuring the webserver and if so, can you also provide a working config we could use?

I'm also open to better suggestions than the two I thought about. Maybe theres something easier and better to achieve this goal.

Thanks in advance
Jan

Comment: would like to know if you are wishing to achieve it via redirection hacks or are you okay with re-installation into document root of the website concerned, the later i guess is more tedious yet trustworthy.

Comment: I would love to hear about both approaches to see the advantages and disadvantages. re-installation shouldn't be a big problem I think as long as we can keep the 2 separate WP installations (because one page is built with a custom theme and the other with a bought one). 

I just don't want to rebuild the sites from scratch and re-use all the data from the database, uploads, layouts etc.

Comment: what happens to your `another-example.com` in case we achieve what you ask here ? I mean what are you planning to do the old url's, are you wishing to discard the domain or   considering to redirect to `example.com/` ?